# Alexa account linking using facebook

Tags: facebook, alexa-skills-kit

I am trying to build an alexa skill, that would have facebook login as an account linking provider. I have built a development version of it that is working with my own account. Now I am thinking of submitting facebook app for review, so I could make my app public and publish alexa skill.

First probably that I encountered is that, I need to specify platform in FB app. The closest one to my use case, might be website. But what url to put in the field. My skill url?

The other thing, is that I want to get users friend-list, which use my app. This scope requires user permission. To get it I have to write how am I going to use that data, how to test it and provide a screencast how it works. There are bunch of requirements like, the button to the login page has to be in FB style, while in alexa app it is just a simple link to login page. Also how to write, testing instructions?

The more I think, the more it seems that it is impossible to have FB service as the account link service for alexa skills. Maybe someone has succeeded to build a working live skill with FB as account linking service and can share your experience?

Answer (score 1):

> What url to put in the field. My skill url?

Yes, but I doubt how a "website" is the closest match to your usecase.

> write how am I going to use that data

Answer how your skills uses the users friend list, why do you want it and how it adds to the user experience of your skill.

> the login page has to be in FB style, while in alexa app it is just a
>   simple link to login page.

This should be fine, mention how login works in Alexa and how your skill users get redirected to FB login page.

> how to write, testing instructions?

Write it step by step and as easy as possible, just like how somebody is going to use it. Create an Amazon test account and add it under beta testers in you Alexa skill. Share this test account along with the instructions.

> The more I think, the more it seems that it is impossible to have FB
>   service as the account link service for alexa skills.

Give it a try, it should be certainly possible. I would have tried it like this.
And wait for their reply. If there are any mistakes or they need any other data/instructions/clarifications, they would hopefully leave a comment.

PS: I don't have any experience in submitting a Facebook app. Checkout other answers as well, this is just my suggestion.

All the best.